# How to expand variables that are in a text file when reading the file into a string?

Tags: php, file, heredoc

In the context of processing html form input and responding by sending email via php, rather than having a lengthy heredoc assignment statement in the middle of my code, I'd like to have the email text in a file and read it in when needed, expanding the embedded variables as required.

Using appropriately prepared HTML form data input, I previously had…

```
$message = <<<TEXT  
NAME: {$_POST["fname"]} {$_POST["lname"]}
POSTAL ADDRESS: {$_POST["postal"]}
EMAIL ADDRESS: {$_POST["email"]}
[... message body etc.]
TEXT;
```

Moving the text to a file I then tried…

```
$message = file_get_contents('filename.txt');
```

…but found that variables in the text are not expanded, resulting in output including the variable identifiers as literals.

Is there a way to expand the variables when reading the file into a string ?

Comment: [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) ??    somethink like this: `str_replace($message,'{$_POST["fname"]}',$_POST["fname"])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably a duplicate, if found I'll delete.  But there are two ways that come to mind:

If you construct your file like this:

```
NAME: {fname} {lname}
```

Then loop the `$_POST` variables:

```
$message = file_get_contents('filename.txt');

foreach($_POST as $key => $val) {
    $message = str_replace('{'.$key.'}', $val, $message);
}
```

If you construct your file like this:

```
NAME: <?= $_POST["fname"] ?> <?= $_POST["lname"] ?>
```

If HTML .txt or other (not .php) then:

```
ob_start();
$file = file_get_contents('filename.txt');
eval($file);
$message = ob_get_clean();
```

If it's a .php file then buffer the output and include:

```
ob_start();
include('filename.php');
$message = ob_get_clean();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help from AbraCadaver I put everything into a function which will handle the file and array, returning the composed message. I constructed the file to use [key] marking the places where data is to be inserted. Works like a charm. Thank you.

```
function compose_message($file, $array) {
    // reads content of $file
    // interpolates values from $array into text of file
    // returns composed message
    $message = file_get_contents($file);
    $keys = array_keys($array);
    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        $message = str_replace("[$key]", $array[$key], $message);
    }
    return $message;
}
```